# Hide original columns after copying and inserting into new columns

Tags: excel, vba

The following VBA code copies the red bordered cells (blue) and inserts them into the green bordered cells.

```vb
Sub ColumnCopyInsert()
    Range("D:E").Copy
  Range("D2").End(xlToRight).Offset(-1, 1).Insert xlToRight
End Sub
```

[image: FUNCTIONALITY VBA]

I would like to add a function to hide column D and E.

If I hide the two columns and copy/insert new columns with my VBA button, they are also hidden.

The goal is to hide D, E not the new columns.

Comment: `Range("D:E").EntireColumn.Hidden = True`

Comment: @FunThomas That is not working, the new colums are hidden too!!

Comment: What is is D2, if row 2 is empty `Range("D2").End(xlToRight)` will go to the end of the sheet.

Comment: @CDP1802 D2 is not allowed to be emtpy

Comment: Is E2  the same ?

Comment: no E2 can be empty @CDP1802

Comment: Do you always want to copy D:E to  F:G or do you want them to go into an empty column  at the end If so what would define an empty column ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Copy Contiguous Columns After Last Column

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ColumnCopyInsert()
    
    Const ColumnsAddress As String = "D:E"
    Const LastColumnRow As Long = 2
    
    With Columns(ColumnsAddress)
        .EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        .Copy
        Dim cCount As Long: cCount = .Columns.Count
        .Cells(LastColumnRow, 1).End(xlToRight) _
            .Offset(1 - LastColumnRow, 1).Insert xlShiftToRight
        .EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: that works fine for me @VBasic2008 But how can I copy D,E and hide D-G. The programm isnt working if I delete F,G

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly: if the last column is `G`, do you want to copy to `H:I` and additionally hide `F:G`? And the same for `I`, `J:K`, hide `H:I`?

Comment: So i want to copy D:E. But there is a bug, so i can´t delete F:G and it inserts first time into H:I. Now it hides D:E what is great. But there is F:G useless columns, what i cant delete. If I delete or hide, vba says error and excel is imediatly crashing everytime! @VBasic2008

Comment: maybe I should consider creating a new question for this fatal bug??

Comment: If you want to overwrite `F:G` every time, you need to copy, not insert. Use the macro recorder to do it manually and see the code.

Comment: not sure what you mean. dont worked with macro recorder

Comment: `.Resize(, cCount).EntireColumn.Hidden = False` is not required because the copied columns have been made visible. However if you test with `.Resize(, cCount).EntireColumn.Interior.Color = vbRed` you see they are the wrong columns anyway.

Comment: @CDP1802: Thanks. I guess that was a leftover from a previous version. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

you can simply add 1 line...

```
Range("F:AA").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
```

Comment: works only limited, debugging process again and again

Comment: it looks like me ant others do not get the essence of your question...
maybe post the pic of all data you have before and how you want to have it after...

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Sub ColumnCopyInsert()

    Dim rng As Range, n As Long
    Set rng = Range("F1")

    ' find empty column
    Do While WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng.EntireColumn) > 0
        Set rng = rng.Offset(, 1)
    Loop
    
    With Range("D:E")
        n = .Columns.Count
        .Copy
        rng.Insert xlToRight
        rng.Offset(0, -n).Resize(, n).EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    End With

End Sub
```